# Alternating group colors SSRS

Tags: visual-studio, reporting-services, formatting, ssrs-2008

I am trying to alternate the colors of my groups taking into account hidden groups.

```
IIF(
(RunningValue(Fields!Column.Value, CountDistinct, Nothing) -
    COUNT(IIF(Fields!Hidden.Value = TRUE, Nothing, 1))) 
 MOD 2 = 1, "Gainsboro", "White"))
```

currently semi-works but it colors the first two groups the same color then alternates after that,  occasionally grouping some groups together.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: If you are taking into account hidden groups, wouldn't the colors on either side of the hidden group be the same?  Also, I usually see this done with RowNumber scoped to the group, not RunningValue.

Comment: Since Groups have many Rows, RunningValue is the way to go on this. Rather than hiding the groups, could you filter the group value out of the dataset either in the SQL, the dataset filter or tablix filter?